# onActivityResult is only called after pushing the backbutton

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning programming with android now, and I build an app, to take a picture with the camera with this tutorial.

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

But onActivity is not called automaticly, it is only called when I push the back button, after taking a picture with my device.

```
package com.olchowski.valentin.cam2dial;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(this, "RENDERING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "PHOTO TAKEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg", storageDir);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are pressing the BACK button in the camera app, and then `onActivityResult()` in your activity is being called?

Comment: Yes, when I start the app, I can take ay many pictures, as I want. And after I press the back button, the onActivityResult() is called. But I wanted to be called after one picture is taken an the user has clicked ok or save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is up to the camera app. There are thousands of device models, shipping with hundreds of different camera apps. Plus, there are camera apps downloadable from the Play Store and elsewhere.

Some have bugs.

In this case, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` *should* return to your app once the user takes a picture. For whatever reason, the implementers of this camera app chose not to do that, or did not test `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` well.

There is nothing you can really do about this, other than not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (e.g., use the camera APIs directly).

Comment: This was the right hint ;-). I tried it, with another device and it worked, as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the photos that you take with camera can't save properly on disk because of using `createTempFile()` method.
also you should give some information about what version of android do you use for test and some more details.
You are using timestamps for naming your photos taken by camera and by default its guarantee that your file names are unique. so using `createTempFile()` method is redundant. I try your code with `new File()` creation method and its worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult()` is called when the Activity you are calling closes so this expected behaviour.

Pressing the "Back" key closes the Activity allowing the result to be delivered.

You cannot get a result from an Activity that is still open.

Comment: Ok, so how can I close the Activity, after a picture is taken, automaticly?

Comment: You probably cant but I would assume it depends on which camera app you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a limitation out of your reach, then the best option is to create your custom activity to capture via a camera. [Here](https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example) is an example on how it can be done. I haven't tested it. But, you should be able to figure it out as it doesn't seem complex.